# Как использовать Polymer в фреймворке Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, polymer

Друзья объясните пожалуйста.
Изучаю Vaadin всего несколько дней, я в упор не понимаю как я могу подключить Polymer? У Vaadin два варианта разработки server-side(default) и client-side.
Используя Polymer мне нужно использовать client-side? или могу так же использовать server-side? 
В голове каша, не могли бы обьяснить или хотя бы задать направление движения мысли.

Answer (score 0):

Веб-компоненты и HTML элементы Java управляется на стороне сервера. Для этого вам необходимо установить node.js и bower. [Learn Polymer with Vaadin Elements](https://vaadin.github.io/elements-codelab/#0) 
и надеюсь следующий видео поможет вам, как правильно подключить библиотеку Polymer c Vaadin.   [Vaadin and Polymer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuAxOsYlWrQ&t=55s)